# Customizer settings using "for" loop

Tags: loop, theme-customizer, settings-api

Please let me know if I'm missing something here - I try to create multiple customizer settings using **for** loop, they don't show up in the customizer though. Here's the code:

```
for ( $i = 1; $i < 7; $i++ ) :

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'home_features_boxes_icon_' . $i, array(
        'default'           => '',
        'type'              => 'theme_mod',
        'capability'        => 'edit_theme_options',
        'sanitize_callback' => 'esc_html',
    ) );
    $wp_customize->add_control( 'home_features_boxes_icon_' . $i . '_c', array(
        'settings'          => 'home_features_boxes_icon' . $i,
        'section'           => 'home_features_boxes',
        'type'              => 'text',
        'label'             => esc_html__( $i . ' - Box Icon', 'lucathemes' ),
    ) );

endfor;
```

Section name is correct, settings added outside the **for** loop are working fine.

Thanks,
Luca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `_` in `add_control` paramater: `settings`.
The `settings` parameter should be `home_features_boxes_icon_' . $i`

Full code here:

```
for ( $i = 1; $i < 7; $i++ ) :

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'home_features_boxes_icon_' . $i, array(
        'default'           => '',
        'type'              => 'theme_mod',
        'capability'        => 'edit_theme_options',
        'sanitize_callback' => 'esc_html',
    ) );
    $wp_customize->add_control( 'home_features_boxes_icon_' . $i . '_c', array(
        'settings'          => 'home_features_boxes_icon_' . $i,
        'section'           => 'home_features_boxes',
        'type'              => 'text',
        'label'             => esc_html__( $i . ' - Box Icon', 'lucathemes' ),
    ) );

endfor;
```

On the side note: `esc_html` is not a sanitization function. Use `sanitize_text_field` for text fields.

Comment: What would I do without smart people :) Thank you!